# Mesh does not move with the Rig

Tags: mesh, rigging

As a summery I used a preexisting model removed it's rig as it does'nt satisfy the requirements, and used a basic human rig in rigify and generated the version as in file.But right now i am stuck in moving the model as my mesh isn't moving with the joint motions.Anyone have idea of where I might have gone wrong?

Blender File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NT1oiu2R7IW5UBJFVDuPxx07A88AaQoR/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well fixed the error,the mesh wasn't selected with the joints, if anyone else come to this point,

After generating the rig as above follow the following steps,
Hide up the additional rigging stuff by H 
select the bone structure, you can find it in the layers in the display menu
Ctrl + Z to get wireframe of the model
select the mesh then the joint structure (Use shift)
Then apply automatic weights (setting joint structure as the parent)

For more info follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dYiAd_08-0k